# Got some error when generate Graphql with gqlgen

Tags: go, graphql, generate, gqlgen

I get an error when I try to generate schema in gqlgen :

type :

```
go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate
```

Errors :

```
..\..\..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\99designs\gqlgen@v0.17.33\main.go:20:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package github.com/urfave/cli/v2 (imported by github.com/99designs/gqlgen); to add:        
        go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.17.33
..\..\..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\99designs\gqlgen@v0.17.33\codegen\field.go:16:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package golang.org/x/text/cases (imported by github.com/99designs/gqlgen/codegen); to add:
        go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen/codegen@v0.17.33
..\..\..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\99designs\gqlgen@v0.17.33\codegen\field.go:17:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package golang.org/x/text/language (imported by github.com/99designs/gqlgen/codegen); to add:
        go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen/codegen@v0.17.33
..\..\..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\99designs\gqlgen@v0.17.33\internal\imports\prune.go:15:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil (imported by github.com/99designs/gqlgen/internal/imports); to add:
        go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen/internal/imports@v0.17.33
..\..\..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\99designs\gqlgen@v0.17.33\internal\code\packages.go:14:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package golang.org/x/tools/go/packages (imported by github.com/99designs/gqlgen/codegen/config); to add:
        go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen/codegen/config@v0.17.33
..\..\..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\99designs\gqlgen@v0.17.33\internal\imports\prune.go:16:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package golang.org/x/tools/imports (imported by github.com/99designs/gqlgen/internal/imports); to add:
        go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen/internal/imports@v0.17.33
```

Comment: first run `go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen/internal/imports@v0.17.33`  , `go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen/codegen@v0.17.33` then run `go mod tidy` and then finally run  `go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate`